# Jenkin's build result identifying "ERROR" if SonarQube quality gate is failed

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have sonarqube integrated with Jenkins thorugh sonarqube plugins. When i run a job in jenkins, It's passing without any issue. SonarQube also running scan without any issue. i can see new results in sonar server. My issue is, at the end of build in summery, If sonarqube quality gate is Failed in result, Jenkins is saying "ERROR" instead of "FAILED". is it normal behavior or it's something wrong in my build that is the reason, it's saying "ERROR". I have configured build steps for sonar as in picture 1. Output i am getting is "ERROR" as picture 2.
[image][image]

as you can see in picture 2 at the end of build, it's says "ERROR". can someone please help me to understand. it's normal behavior or not?
I have 
jenkins version 2.59
sonar server version 5.6
sonar-scanner-3.0.3.778 for MSBuild

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Jenkins build will fail, if we configure Quality Gates on a project.
If you don't want the build to fail bases on Quality Gates output, you can add Post Build Actions. And can change the build status to unstable or successful using a Groovy Post Build Script.

Comment: Jenkins build is not failing. You have an option in SonarQube plugin to setup a build unstable or successful. We don't need to write any post build script for it. As i mentioned in question, I am getting "ERROR" in summary of SonarQube Quality Gate analysis.